# Better way to write recursive random variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, discord, discord.py

I know this is really bad, but it works and it was the only way with my current knowledge to complete the job. So I am looking for a "better" way in practice to write this.

Basically it shows 3 slots of images and those 3 slots change images with the random images listed in `SLOT_PATTERN`. The images change using `edit_message` to edit the previous 3 slot images that were there, replacing them with random images from the given list.

```
import discord, asyncio, time, random

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    SLOT_PATTERN = [':four_leaf_clover:', ':moneybag:', ':cherries:', ':lemon:', ':grapes:', ':poop:', ':bell:', ':chocolate_bar:', ':watermelon:', ':six:', ':seven:', ':crown:']

    wheel_pick1 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick2 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick3 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick4 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick5 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick6 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick7 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick8 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick9 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick10 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick11 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick12 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick13 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick14 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick15 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick16 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick17 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick18 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick19 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick20 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick21 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick22 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick23 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick24 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick25 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick26 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick27 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick28 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick29 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
    wheel_pick30 = SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]

    if message.content.lower().startswith("!slots"):
        slot1 = await client.send_message(message.channel, '%s %s %s' % (wheel_pick1, wheel_pick2, wheel_pick3))
        time.sleep(0.25)
        slot2 = await client.edit_message(slot1, '%s %s %s' % (wheel_pick4, wheel_pick5, wheel_pick6))
        time.sleep(0.25)
        slot3 = await client.edit_message(slot2, '%s %s %s' % (wheel_pick7, wheel_pick8, wheel_pick9))
        time.sleep(0.50)
        slot4 = await client.edit_message(slot3, '%s %s %s' % (wheel_pick10, wheel_pick11, wheel_pick12))
        time.sleep(0.50)
        slot5 = await client.edit_message(slot4, '%s %s %s' % (wheel_pick13, wheel_pick14, wheel_pick15))
        time.sleep(0.75)
        slot6 = await client.edit_message(slot5, '%s %s %s' % (wheel_pick16, wheel_pick17, wheel_pick18))
        time.sleep(0.75)
        slot7 = await client.edit_message(slot6, '%s %s %s' % (wheel_pick19, wheel_pick20, wheel_pick21))
        time.sleep(1)
        slot8 = await client.edit_message(slot7, '%s %s %s' % (wheel_pick22, wheel_pick23, wheel_pick24))
        time.sleep(1)
        slot9 = await client.edit_message(slot8, '%s %s %s' % (wheel_pick25, wheel_pick26, wheel_pick27))
        time.sleep(1)
        await client.edit_message(slot9, '%s %s %s' % (wheel_pick28, wheel_pick29, wheel_pick30))

client.run('clienttokenhere')
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a function!

```
def wheel():
    return SLOT_PATTERN[random.randint(0, len(SLOT_PATTERN) - 1)]
```

And a list of timings:

```
INTERVALS = [0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1]
```

Then:

```
def wheels(n):
    return ' '.join(wheel() for _ in range(n))

if message.content.lower().startswith("!slots"):
    slot = await client.send_message(message.channel, wheels(3))

    for interval in INTERVALS:
        time.sleep(interval)
        slot = await client.edit_message(slot, wheels(3))
```

Comment: Wow, this is a very elegant solution now that I actually see it. Thanks!

Comment: @user152294: You're welcome.  Whenever you find yourself copy-pasting the same code more than twice, just always remember you can turn it into a function or a loop.

Comment: Yo, `random.choice` for that first function