# Discord Bot game emoji

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hello i created a game with emoji below is my code its working fine.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def game(ctx):
    slots = ['bus', 'train', 'horse', 'tiger', 'monkey', 'cow']
    slot1 = slots[random.randint(0, 5)]
    slot2 = slots[random.randint(0, 5)]

    slotOutput = '| :{}: | :{}: |\n'.format(slot1, slot2)

    if slot1 == slot2:
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "{}\nWon".format(slotOutput))

    else:
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "{}\nLost".format(slotOutput))
```

But how to make emoji running in random select like below image.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Patrick's answer, You seem to just immediately post the result, when what you want to do instead is post the wheels spinning and then edit it into the results

```
# You shouldn't trust Discord to handle :emotes: properly. For unicode
# emotes, use the codepoint \N{NAME} or \U0001Fxxx, for custom emotes
# use <:_:EMOTE_ID> or <a:_:ANIMOTE_ID>
slots = ["\N{MONKEY FACE}", "\N{COW FACE}", "\N{TIGER_FACE}", 
         "\N{HORSE FACE}", "\N{BUS}", "\N{STEAM LOCOMOTIVE}"]

# choice(v) is same as v[randrange(len(v))]
results = [random.choice(slots), random.choice(slots)]

msg = await bot.send_message("| {0} | {0} |".format("<a:slot_spin:EMOJI_ID>"))
# Note you will need to create the emote and put it on a server the bot can see

for show in range(len(results)):
    await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(1, 4))
    disp = [v if show <= i else "<a:_:...>" # Only show indexes below the show number
            for i, v in enumerate(results)] # enumerate returns [(0, results[0]), ...]
    bot.edit_message(msg, "| {0[0]} | {0[1]} |".format(disp))
```

Comment: Is the `<a...>` syntax necessary for animated emoji, or could they be represented by `discord.Emoji` objects?

Comment: @Patrick Haugh the <a...> syntax is the simplest way to add them to a message, Plus in /async, which is what OP is using, discord.Emoji doesn't even differentiate animated from regular emoji.

Comment: @Demotry yeah, that's the kind of code you'd add into your command function.

Comment: Fixed. A bracket wasn't closed.

Comment: Read the comments. You will need to create an animated emote for the bot to use, then substitute in the ID of that emote. You can see an emote's ID by prefixing it with a \\ before posting it to chat, e.g. `\:ablobcatbounce:` would post `<a:ablobcatbounce:EMOTE_ID>` and that's what you need to paste in.

Comment: I said yesterday. You can't use `:NAME:` format when working with bots, you *have* to use `<a:NAME:ID>` format

Answer (score 1):

to do that you would want to just do a basic loop running for however long you want to spin for. Every time it loops, you would edit the message (`.edit`) to change the emojis there. Hope that helps.

Comment: Well, it's pretty simple. When the command is called, you would send a message with the three emojis. Then after that you would do a loop in which under you would randomly create combinations. You would create a new embed with those random emojis and edit the old one with the new one. I'm assuming you are using async so if you need help, use [the async docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or the [rewrite docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/)

Comment: Okay, well life isn't fair - you can't always get want you want. Sorry, but that is the truth. I have also given you some good advice and a literal tutorial in my answer and comment.

Answer (score 1):

Those are animated emoji.  The message is being edited three times, to "freeze" the emoji by replacing it with a static emoji.  I believe that your bot would need to be in a server owned by someone with Discord Nitro with those custom emoji.  Then your bot would be able to use those emoji even in other servers.

Comment: Yes i have Nitro so how to do that any example code ?

Comment: No, I've never done this before (And I don't have Nitro). I would recommend breaking this into two experiments: displaying the animated cycling emoji, potentially from a different server, and editing the embed to freeze them in their final positions.

Comment: I seen some other posts which have answers. So can you check it once and help me to edit my code if its possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223582/better-way-to-write-recursive-random-variables

Comment: You need to make 3 seperate edits. One edit to show [1] [?] [?], a second for [1] [2] [?] and then a final third edit to show all 3 emotes stopped. e: 2 seperate edits since your slot machine only has 2 wheels.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go lad, I'm an autistic coder but this does work 100%; it's running on my bot right now, hope it helps, (and yes, bots have perms to use animated emojis but you don't).

You need to go to the emoji selector in discord after adding it to your `custom emoji list`, and then do ctrl+shift+i to `inspect element` and pull the ID for it which you need to define, you can see examples of animated emoji definition inside my source code, Enjoy :)

(IDK how to make it post to be python so if it looks stupid. Try to copy-paste it, otherwise, contact me and I can just send you the file with it inside.)

```
@bot.command()
async def game(ctx):
await ctx.message.delete()
parrot = '<a:parrot:498460603300446238>'
slotspin = '<a:heartgif:498082283077500938>'
slots = [':blue_heart:', ':blue_heart:', ':blue_heart:', ':purple_heart:', ':heart:', ':yellow_heart:', ':green_heart:', ':green_heart:', ':green_heart:', ':green_heart:', ':green_heart:', ':green_heart:']
slot1 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot2 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot3 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot4 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot5 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot6 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot7 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot8 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot9 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot10 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot11 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot12 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot13 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot14 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot15 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot16 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot17 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot18 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot19 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot20 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot21 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot22 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot23 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot24 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]
slot25 = slots[random.randint(0, 11)]

slotOutput = '| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n'.format(slot1, slot2, slot3, slot4, slot5, slot6, slot7, slot8, slot9, slot10, slot11, slot12, slot13, slot14, slot15, slot16, slot17, slot18, slot19, slot20, slot21, slot22, slot23, slot24, slot25)
slotOutput1 = '| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n'.format(slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin,)
results0 = '| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n'.format(parrot, parrot, parrot, parrot, parrot, slot6, slot7, slot8, slot9, slot10, slot11, slot12, slot13, slot14, slot15, slot16, slot17, slot18, slot19, slot20, slot21, slot22, slot23, slot24, slot25)
results1 = '| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n'.format(slot1, slot2, slot3, slot4, slot5, parrot, parrot, parrot, parrot, parrot, slot11, slot12, slot13, slot14, slot15, slot16, slot17, slot18, slot19, slot20, slot21, slot22, slot23, slot24, slot25)
results2 = '| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n'.format(slot1, slot2, slot3, slot4, slot5, slot6, slot7, slot8, slot9, slot10, parrot, parrot, parrot, parrot, parrot, slot16, slot17, slot18, slot19, slot20, slot21, slot22, slot23, slot24, slot25)
results3 = '| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n'.format(slot1, slot2, slot3, slot4, slot5, slot6, slot7, slot8, slot9, slot10, slot11, slot12, slot13, slot14, slot15, parrot, parrot, parrot, parrot, parrot, slot21, slot22, slot23, slot24, slot25)
results4 = '| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n'.format(slot1, slot2, slot3, slot4, slot5, slot6, slot7, slot8, slot9, slot10, slot11, slot12, slot13, slot14, slot15, slot16, slot17, slot18, slot19, slot20, parrot, parrot, parrot, parrot, parrot)
results5 = '| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n'.format(parrot, slot2, slot3, slot4, slot5, parrot, slot7, slot8, slot9, slot10, parrot, slot12, slot13, slot14, slot15, parrot, slot17, slot18, slot19, slot20, parrot, slot22, slot23, slot24, slot25)
results6 = '| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n'.format(slot1, parrot, slot3, slot4, slot5, slot6, parrot, slot8, slot9, slot10, slot11, parrot, slot13, slot14, slot15, slot16, parrot, slot18, slot19, slot20, slot21, parrot, slot23, slot24, slot25)
results7 = '| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n'.format(slot1, slot2, parrot, slot4, slot5, slot6, slot7, parrot, slot9, slot10, slot11, slot12, parrot, slot14, slot15, slot16, slot17, parrot, slot19, slot20, slot21, slot22, parrot, slot24, slot25)
results8 = '| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n'.format(slot1, slot2, slot3, parrot, slot5, slot6, slot7, slot8, parrot, slot10, slot11, slot12, slot13, parrot, slot15, slot16, slot17, slot18, parrot, slot20, slot21, slot22, slot23, parrot, slot25)
results9 = '| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n'.format(slot1, slot2, slot3, slot4, parrot, slot6, slot7, slot8, slot9, parrot, slot11, slot12, slot13, slot14, parrot, slot16, slot17, slot18, slot19, parrot, slot21, slot22, slot23, slot24, parrot)
results10 = '| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n'.format(parrot, slot2, slot3, slot4, slot5, slot6, parrot, slot8, slot9, slot10, slot11, slot12, parrot, slot14, slot15, slot16, slot17, slot18, parrot, slot20, slot21, slot22, slot23, slot24, parrot)
results11 = '| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n'.format(slot1, slot2, slot3, slot4, parrot, slot6, slot7, slot8, parrot, slot10, slot11, slot12, parrot, slot14, slot15, slot16, parrot, slot18, slot19, slot20, parrot, slot22, slot23, slot24, slot25)

msg = await ctx.message.channel.send("{}\n {} Is Spinning".format(slotOutput1,ctx.message.author.mention))
await asyncio.sleep(2)
await msg.edit(content='| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n {} Is Spinning'.format(slot1, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slot6, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slot11, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slot16, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slot21, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, ctx.message.author.mention))
await asyncio.sleep(2)
await msg.edit(content='| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n {} Is Spinning'.format(slot1, slot2, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slot6, slot7, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slot11, slot12, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slot16, slot17, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, slot21, slot22, slotspin, slotspin, slotspin, ctx.message.author.mention))
await asyncio.sleep(2)
await msg.edit(content='| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n {} Is Spinning'.format(slot1, slot2, slot3, slotspin, slotspin, slot6, slot7, slot8, slotspin, slotspin, slot11, slot12, slot13, slotspin, slotspin, slot16, slot17, slot18, slotspin, slotspin, slot21, slot22, slot23, slotspin, slotspin, ctx.message.author.mention))
await asyncio.sleep(2)
await msg.edit(content='| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n {} Is Spinning'.format(slot1, slot2, slot3, slot4, slotspin, slot6, slot7, slot8, slot9, slotspin, slot11, slot12, slot13, slot14, slotspin, slot16, slot17, slot18, slot19, slotspin, slot21, slot22, slot23, slot24, slotspin, ctx.message.author.mention))
await asyncio.sleep(2)
await msg.edit(content='| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n {} Is Spinning'.format(slot1, slot2, slot3, slot4, slot5, slot6, slot7, slot8, slot9, slot10, slot11, slot12, slot13, slot14, slot15, slot16, slot17, slot18, slot19, slot20, slot21, slot22, slot23, slot24, slot25, ctx.message.author.mention))

if slot1 == slot2 == slot3 == slot4 == slot5:
    #await ctx.message.channel.send( "{}\n {} You Won".format(slotOutput,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=5)
    await msg.edit(content="{}\n {} You Won".format(results0,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=3)
elif slot6 == slot7 == slot8 == slot9 == slot10:
    #await ctx.message.channel.send( "{}\n {} You Won".format(slotOutput,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=5)
    await msg.edit(content="{}\n {} You Won".format(results1,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=3)
elif slot11 == slot12 == slot13 == slot14 == slot15:
    #await ctx.message.channel.send( "{}\n {} You Won".format(slotOutput,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=5)
    await msg.edit(content="{}\n {} You Won".format(results2,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=3)
elif slot16 == slot17 == slot18 == slot19 == slot20:
    #await ctx.message.channel.send( "{}\n {} You Won".format(slotOutput,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=5)
    await msg.edit(content="{}\n {} You Won".format(results3,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=3)
elif slot21 == slot22 == slot23 == slot24 == slot25:
    #await ctx.message.channel.send( "{}\n {} You Won".format(slotOutput,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=5)
    await msg.edit(content="{}\n {} You Won".format(results4,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=3)
elif slot1 == slot6 == slot11 == slot16 == slot21:
    #await ctx.message.channel.send( "{}\n {} You Won".format(slotOutput,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=5)
    await msg.edit(content="{}\n {} You Won".format(results5,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=3)
elif slot2 == slot7 == slot12 == slot17 == slot22:
    #await ctx.message.channel.send( "{}\n {} You Won".format(slotOutput,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=5)
    await msg.edit(content="{}\n {} You Won".format(results6,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=3)
elif slot3 == slot8 == slot13 == slot18 == slot23:
    #await ctx.message.channel.send( "{}\n {} You Won".format(slotOutput,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=5)
    await msg.edit(content="{}\n {} You Won".format(results7,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=3)
elif slot4 == slot9 == slot14 == slot19 == slot24:
    #await ctx.message.channel.send( "{}\n {} You Won".format(slotOutput,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=5)
    await msg.edit(content="{}\n {} You Won".format(results8,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=3)
elif slot5 == slot10 == slot15 == slot20 == slot25:
    #await ctx.message.channel.send( "{}\n {} You Won".format(slotOutput,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=5)
    await msg.edit(content="{}\n {} You Won".format(results9,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=3)
elif slot1 == slot7 == slot13 == slot19 == slot25:
    #await ctx.message.channel.send( "{}\n {} You Won".format(slotOutput,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=5)
    await msg.edit(content="{}\n {} You Won".format(results10,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=3)
elif slot5 == slot9 == slot13 == slot17 == slot21:
    #await ctx.message.channel.send( "{}\n {} You Won".format(slotOutput,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=5)
    await msg.edit(content="{}\n {} You Won".format(results11,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=3)
else:
    #await ctx.message.channel.send("{}\n {} You Lost".format(slotOutput,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=5)
    await msg.edit(content="{}\n {} You Lost".format(slotOutput,ctx.message.author.mention),delete_after=3)
```